# Чтение файла выводит пустоту NodeJS модуль fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

```
const user = {
 name: 'Vlad',
 surname: 'NN'
}
```

```
(async () => {
 await fs.writeFileSync('users.json', JSON.stringify(user));
 const users = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('users.json', 'utf8'));
 console.log(users);
})();
```

Если повторно запустить, то выводит. Почему так?

Comment: Зачем применяя синхронные методы оборачивать это все в `async()`, да и еще использовать `await`? И без точки с запятой перед `(async()...` тут должна быть ошибка.

Comment: Проверил ваш код, сразу выводится то что нужно. Напишите полный код скрипта сюда и протестируйте сами его на рабочем столе, чтобы точно была ошибка.